# Can I get topics distribution of a word in LDA?

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I'm new to LDA and I want to calculate the topic similarity between words. Can I get the topic distribution of a word? If so, how can I do this in gensim.ldamodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gensim's LDA mallet wrapper has a `load_word_topics()` function (I would assume this is true for its python LDA implementation as well).  It returns a matrix that is words X topics.  From that, you can get a vector of frequencies each word in each topic.  That would be the topic-word distribution for a given word.

Comment: Suppose there is a word "book", and three topics 1, 2, 3. I want to get the distribution 
 of "book", such as 1:0.5 2:0.3 3:0.2. In other word, they must be sum up to 1, not just the item in topic-word distribution. Is it work like that?

Comment: You would just normalize the frequencies based on the total frequencies.

Comment: In gensim, ldamodel.state.get_lambda() seems to return the frequencies, and I normalize it to get the word-topic distribution. Thank you.